# What are these small long narrow yellow things?

Tags: indian-cuisine

In a food market, on the street, I bought a Masala Dosa, and it had some small yellow narrow long things in it that were delicious. I snapped a picture:

[image]

Any ideas what they are?

Comment: What was the dish?

Comment: @SAJ14SAJ It was Masala Dosa.

Comment: Don't know the name, but my Indian boss says it's a fried lentil noodle.

Comment: Just curious to know where you got this Masala Dosa from, because I have had it in so many different cities of India, and never found this 'sev' inside the masala!! :)

Answer (score 16):

They are fried chickpea noodles called "sev".

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sev_(food)

Usually they are added to street food snacks such as bhel puri and pani puri, for example see what a nice look they add to this panipuri 
http://food4yourmood.files.wordpress.com/2013/05/pani-puri.jpg

I usually buy them in Indian grocery stores, though I would think it's also possible to dry roast wheat vermicelli as a substitute.

Comment: This answer seems the right one, as they were crunchy, so it makes sense they were fried.

Answer (score 6):

The " small narrow long yellow " things you are referring to, is called "sev" in India.
It is made up of fried black gram flour. And yes black gram flour is yellow in color.
So, basically you make a batter out of the flour and it is passed through a very thin sieve and directly in to boiling oil.

Answer (score 1):

The objects pictured are thin pasta which is sometimes sold as angel hair, pilaf noodles, fine egg noodles, chayreyé, or broken vermicelli.  Generally, one would sauté them in oil or butter until lightly browned then add them to a stew, curry, or soup so they can absorb some of the flavorful broth.  The sautéing helps keep them from falling apart.

Answer (score 0):

It's similar to what you get in Bombay mix

Comment: And what are the yellow things in Bombay mix then? I'm afraid the answer doesn't get us much further.